# Several errors in Swift when using || or && logical operators

Tags: swift, logical-operators

Got this piece of code:

```
if (self.competitionData.competitionList == nil) || (renewCache) {  
    // <things to be done> 
}
```

where `renewCache` is a `Bool`.

I'm getting the following errors on this line:

- Expected '{' after 'if' condition
- Braced block of statements is an unused closure
- Invalid character in source file

but AFAIK I think it's correct. What's the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a basic syntax error. Would have marked it as "Too Localized" in past revs of SO closing options.

Comment: I can't do anything to get this code to generate an error (and indeed, the only thing I see that's marginal is enclosing `renewCache` in parens, which is unnecessary and mostly pointless.  If you're still having this problem you need to post the rest of the problem context, a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: My best guess: remove the text between if and { completely and type it new manually (not copy/paste!). Maybe you got some wrong utf-8 char you can't see.

Comment: I like @ThomasKilian's idea. The third error you listed actually says pretty much what he's saying: `Invalid character in source file` There are a number of Unicode characters (and therefore UTF-8) which could look like a normal space or even not show up and cause problems with your source code. Did you copy the code from a web page somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally I found the problem.

It's not related with this line at all, but a sentence like 10 lines below in a method call where I was passing the second parameter without parameter name. By the way, that line wasn't marked as error by XCode :-(

it seems that the XCode Swift parser has some problems identifying the correct line of your error.

After fixing the problem, that line is compiled ok.

Answer (score -2):

Try with extra parentheses:

```
if ((self.competitionData.competitionList == nil) || (renewCache)) {
}
```

This is the problem, only need extra-parentheses for conditions :)

PD: Sorry, fixed

Comment: In a swift if statement, the condition is not required to be enclosed in ().